# Клонирование/дублирование выпадающего списка JS

Tags: javascript, html, клонирование

Имеется список:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title>TeamWorkAPI</title>
 <script id="RTCEarlyScript" type="text/javascript">
  window.oldSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;
  window.setTimeout = function(func, delay) {
   return window.oldSetTimeout(function() {
    try {
     if (!document.documentElement.getAttribute('stopTimers')) {
      if (typeof func == 'string') {
       varnfunc = new Function(func);
       nfunc();
      } else func();
     }
    } catch (ex) {}
   }, delay);
  };
  window.oldSetInterval = window.setInterval;
  window.setInterval = function(func, delay) {
   return window.oldSetInterval(function() {
    try {
     if (!document.documentElement.getAttribute('stopTimers')) {
      if (typeof func == 'string') {
       varnfunc = new Function(func);
       nfunc();
      } else func();
     }
    } catch (ex) {}
   }, delay);
  };
 </script>
</head>
<p><b><h1>Назначение бригады СМП</h1></b>
    <form name="subscribe" id="subscribe_frm" action="#">
        <b>Выбор подстанции СМП</b><br>
        <select id="Podstantsiya" name="form1">
<option value = " Восточный ">Восточная подстанция</option>
<option value = " Центральный ">Центральная подстанция</option>
</select><br><br>
<b>Добавление подстанции</b><br>
<form>
<input type=button onclick=clone()>
</form>

<input type="date" name="form 6" id="vozrast" /> - Возраст (В формате дд.мм.гггг) <br><br>
<input type="text" name="form2" id="adres" /> - Адрес<br><br>
<input type="text" name="form4" id="clok" /> - Дата и время<br><br>
<input type="text" name="form5" id="nomer" /> - Контактный телефон<br><br>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Отправить" onclick="posttask() + alert('Выполненно!');" />
</form>
```

Нужно сделать так что бы по нажатии кнопки дублировался/клонировался список с этими же значениями. Много вариантов испробовал но так и не нашел способа.
Попробовал вот таким макаром:

```html
<html>
<body>
<p><b><h1>Назначение бригады СМП</h1></b>
    <form name="subscribe" id="subscribe_frm" action="#">
        <b>Выбор подстанции СМП</b><br>
        <select id="Podstantsiya" name="form1">
<option value = " Восточный ">Восточная подстанция</option>
<option value = " Центральный ">Центральная подстанция</option>
</select><br><br>
<b>Добавление подстанции</b><br>
<form>
<input type=button onclick=clone()>
<script>
function clone(){
var obj = { a: 1 };
var copy = Object.assign({Podstantsiya}, obj);
console.log(copy);
}
</script>
</form>
</body>
```

При этом что то происходит, вижу что тут 'var obj = { a: 1 };' на до на что то исправить, но на что?

Comment: `Много вариантов испробовал` - например?

Comment: Пытался через 'document.getElementById' сделать, 'exports.copyObject = function(obj)'. Там еще были какие то способы, может я их не правильно применял или создавал. Я так сказать начинающий в этой сфере.

Comment: Можешь в вопрос добавить весь код

Comment: Можно абсолютно весь код добавить но думаю будет излишне, основное действие будет происходить с другим выпадающим списком, этот для примера.

Comment: Функция clone() не описана. Код выдает ошибку "Uncaught ReferenceError: clone is not defined" и непонятно зачем нужен js-код с таймаутами для данного вопроса.

Comment: вы абсолютно не правильно понимаете назначение Object.assgn и сущность DOM объекта.